# Rails: Building a link_to link with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models in my **routes.rb**:

```
  resources :products do
    resources :departments, :revenues
  end
```

I'm trying to link to a product's department from the department **show.html** like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= link_to product_department_path(:id => product.id) do %><li><%= product.name %></li><% end %>
    <% end %>
```

What this is doing is giving me HTML like this:

```
<ul>

      <a href="/products/2/departments/1"><li>Product1</li></a>
      <a href="/products/2/departments/2"><li>Product2</li></a>
      <a href="/products/2/departments/3"><li>Product3</li></a>
      <a href="/products/2/departments/5"><li>Product4</li></a>

  </ul>
```

What I really need is this:

```
<ul>

      <a href="/products/1/departments/"><li>Product1</li></a>
      <a href="/products/2/departments/"><li>Product2</li></a>
      <a href="/products/3/departments/"><li>Product3</li></a>
      <a href="/products/4/departments/"><li>Product4</li></a>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little verbose, so I have simplified it. I think you want product_departments_path

```
<li>
  <%= link_to product.name, product_departments_path(product) %>
</li>
```